# Not to match a pattern from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having the following string,

```
var str = "/\S\w\djoseph/";
```

I just wanted to fetch the characters that are not in the following pattern,

```
/\\(\w|\d)/
```

I mean I just want to extract **joseph** from the above string. I have tried with the following but my regex is not working as expected.

```
var str = "/\S\w\djoseph/";
var mat = /[^\\(\w|\d)]/g.exec(str);

console.log(mat); //["/"]
```

Can anyone help me to get the required string from the target string of mine?

Comment: Try `console.log(/\S\w\djoseph/.source.replace(/^((?:\\.)+)(.*)/, function (m,g1,g2) { return g1+g2.toUpperCase(); }))`

Comment: *I mean I just want to extract `joseph` from the above string*  - what is the rule here? Can the input be `/^\Sjoseph(?:\r?\n| )conrad:\s*(?!1990$)\d+$/`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It will not work for this string, `console.log(/\S\w\djoseph\w\w/.source.replace(/^((?:\\.)+)(.*)/, function (m,g1,g2) { return g1+g2.toUpperCase(); }))`

Comment: See my comment above - *what are the rules*? If you only need to remove the shorthand classes, use `str.replace(/\\[swd]/gi, '')`. Your question is too unclear for the time being.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am looking for a regular expression that has to select only the characters that is not followed by "\", For example, `/\wHello\d/` I want to select only "Hello" from this source string, I just want to manipulate it("Hello") as per my requirement.

Comment: Use two backticks to escape ``\``: `\`\`\\`\``. Please add clarifications to the question, and show the real code you tried, since with `exec`, you can only *extract* a part of the string, but not *change* it.

Comment: @anubhava `var x = /\S\whello\s\d/.source.replace(/someRegex/, function(c){
   return c.toUpperCase();
}); console.log(x); // "/\S\wHELLO\s\d/"`

Comment: @anubhava I am looking for that `someRegex` in my previous comment. You have given the inverse of what I wanted. I hope I am clear now.

Comment: @Mediocre: So, you insist on using `RegExp#exec`? That is not efficient. You will need to use something like `/\\.|([^\\]+)/g` and grab Group 1.

Comment: @anubhava I just want it to print `"/\S\wHELLO\s\d/"` not `"HELLO"` only.

Comment: ah ok, check my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex in `.replace` with a callback:

```
/\S\whello\s\d/.source.replace(/(\\[wsd])|(.)/g, function($0, $1, $2){
    return ($1 == undefined ? "" : $1) + ($2 != undefined ? $2.toUpperCase() : ""); 
})

//=> "\S\wHELLO\s\d"
```

This will uppercase anything that is not `\w` or `\s` or `\d`.

Comment: This sounds useful. But Why did you change the source string? It has be `var str = "/\S\w\djoseph/";` Basically I am getting the source string from a regex object like `/test\d/.source`

Comment: Yeah.. But this is also giving me the same result, `/\S\w\djoseph/g.source.replace(/\\./g, "");`. Ok let me come to the point, I just want to make my source string as `'/\\S\\w\\dJOSEPH/'`. That is why I have asked a regex to not to select the `"\S\w\d"`. So that I could manipulate the rest of the characters as per my requirement. Here I just transformed to uppercase for an illustration.

Comment: Superb! +1 It is limited to `[wsd]`. what if we want to match all the characters/numbers/anything followed by "\" ? I managed to modify it by `/(\\[.])|(.)/` But this one broke the logic.

Comment: I am accepting your answer as it solved my problem. But It would be great if you address the issue I have mentioned above. Thanks. :)

Comment: Untested but you can try `/(\\.)|(.)/g`

Comment: I just tested with `/\S\whello\s\d\h\R/.source.replace(/(\\.)|([^\\]+)/g, function($0, $1, $2){
    return ($1 == undefined ? "" : $1) + ($2 != undefined ? $2.toUpperCase() : ""); 
})` and got: `\S\wHELLO\s\d\h\R` as output.

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing everything that matches `\.` with the empty string?

`var a = '\\a\\btest\\c\\d';
var result = a.replace(/\\./g, '');
console.log(result);`